# How to get the picture of what the camera covers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Question: how to get the limits of the camera when it is with the pixel perfect effect since having this applied changes the size of what it captures. unity-c#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Camera.Bounds`. It being controlled by cinemachine does not matter if you're just trying to read the values

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need? At least it solves "get the picture of what camera covers"

```
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture( size, size, 16 );
Camera.main.targetTexture = rt;
RenderTexture.active = rt ;
Texture2D virtualPhoto = new Texture2D( size, size, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false );
virtualPhoto.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, size, size ), 0, 0 );
byte[] itemBGBytes = newTexture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes( Application.dataPath + "/Image.png", itemBGBytes );
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```